# Sending powershell command to remote server with credentials form C# winform

Tags: c#, powershell

Hoping someone can help with this one, have tried a few different approaches.

I have a C# Winforms application that is run by USER1 (the end user - e.g. asmith).

When USER1 opens the C# app, the app collects the logged in username and populates the value into a text field, as shown below:

```cs
txtUsername.Text = Environment.UserName;
```

`txtUsername.Text` value is: `asmith` (as an example)

When USER1 (`asmith`) presses the submit button I need the application to run a PowerShell script on a remote server with the credentials of USER2 (e.g. username: adminUser, pass: reallylongpassword), which should be embedded within the C# app.

The PowerShell command that is run also sends the variable `$localuser` (USER1 - the enduser) with the PowerShell command. e.g.

```
\\scriptserver\scripts\run-script.ps1 $localuser
```

I have got as far as "hardcoding" the end-user's username into the variable for $localuser and running the C# application with USER2 (the admin privileged user) logged in.

Did this as a test to check the application would at least run the application and PowerShell command when hitting the Submit button.

It runs the application, but I do not get any display of the PowerShell output on screen, but I know the script has run because it sends me an email when it's completed.

Unfortunately, the script has not picked up the the `$localuser` variable value when running the PowerShell script as the email I receive has no value where the `$localuser` value should be displayed in the email.

Instead I get in the email, "Requested has been denied for          " blank where the username value should be.

No issues with the actual PowerShell script as this has been tried and tested when run locally as an admin and the value for `$localuser` is hardcoded in PowerShell before running the below command, so that's not it:

```
\\scriptserver\scripts\run-script.ps1 $localuser
```

So, hoping you can help with the issues I have when running the PowerShell from the C# app.

1. Need the application to be run when USER1 (end user - a lower privileged account, but does have local admin rights) is logged in, and when USER1 selects the Submit button the PowerShell command is run on the remote server with the USER2 (admin credentials hardcoded into the application) and sending the USER1 (end user) as the `$localuser` value.
   e.g.

```
\\scriptserver\scripts\run-script.ps1 $localuser
```

$localuser = asmith (as the logged in user running the application)
The PowerShell script is run with USER2 (hardcoded admin credentials) permissions.
Here is my code overall code in the C# application below:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

namespace appEPV3
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // get username and display in textbox
            txtUsername.Text = Environment.UserName;
        }

        private string RunScript(string localuser)
        {
            // create ps runspace
            Runspace rsp = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

            // open it
            rsp.Open();

            // create pipeline and feed it the script text

            Pipeline ppl = rsp.CreatePipeline();
            ppl.Commands.AddScript(@"\\scriptserver\scripts\run-script.ps1 $localuser");
            
            ppl.Commands.Add("Out-String");

            // execute the script
            Collection<PSObject> results = ppl.Invoke();

            // close the runspace
            rsp.Close();

            // convert the script result into a single string

            StringBuilder sbldr = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (PSObject obj in results)
            {
                sbldr.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
            }

            return sbldr.ToString();
        }


        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var localuser = txtUsername.Text;
            txtStatus.Text = txtUsername.Text;
            RunScript(localuser);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I think you need two lines: `ppl.Commands.AddScript(@"\\scriptserver\scripts\run-script.ps1");` followed by `ppl.Commands.AddParameter(localuser);`. The PowerShell script should of course expect this parameter in its `param([string]$localUser)` block at the beginning.

Comment: The powershell script is expecting the parameter as you have stated. Is there another dependency that I need to include before I can use .AddParameter. States CommandCollection does not contain a definition for AddParameter.